# in gnuplot terminals wxt and pngcairo nor available

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, gnuplot

I installed gnuplot version 4.6.6.
After that the terminals "wxt" and "pngcairo" were no longer available. The time before I have been working a lot with these two terminals with version 4.4 and with very good results.

How can I get these two terminals working with gnuplot version 4.6?

In the following I try to answer a question of Christoph:

I am working with Linux, with an old version of Kubuntu (Ubuntu 11.10 "oneiric").
I downloaded "gnuplot-4.6.6", unpacked it and read the File "INSTALL".

```
From this long text I read only the following lines:
----------------------------------------------
Unix, configure
---------------
On Unix, use
$ ./configure
$ make
[ Optionally run demos--see "How to test gnuplot" below. ]
$ make install
-----------------------------------------------
and also the following lines:
----------------------------------------------------------
Linux
-----
Ubuntu:
./configure fails to find lua support because Ubuntu packages it as
"lua5.1" rather than "lua".  You can fix this by adding a symlink
prior to running ./configure
    ln -s /usr/lib/pkgconfig/lua5.1.pc  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/lua.pc
-----------------------------------------------------------

So I applied the following statements (as root):  
'ln -s /usr/lib/pkgconfig/lua5.1.pc  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/lua.pc'
./configure
make
make install
```

All these statements produced a lot of output, but no problems were indicated.
The executable binary program is located in "/usr/local/bin".
My old gnuplot 4.4 is located in "usr/bin".I installed gnuplot version 4.6.6. After that the terminals "wxt" and "pngcairo" were no longer available. The time before I have been working a lot with these two terminals with version 4.4 and with very good results.

How can I get these two terminals working with gnuplot version 4.6?

Comment: Gnuplot can be compiled with a lot of different terminals. If you want to compile with the cairo-based terminals, you must have a lot of development packages installed. If you don't, you don't get an error, but gnuplot is simply built without the respective terminal. At the end of `./configure` call you get a summary which tells you which options are enabled, and which terminals are built (`gnuplot will be compiled with the following terminals: ...wxt terminal: yes/no ... cairo-based pdf and png terminals: yes/no`)

Comment: Thank you Christoph for the quick reply. But I don't know yet what to do. How can I get the development packages installed? During the installation process of gnuplot-4.6.6 I didn't get any question yes/no.

Comment: Maybe stackoverflow is not the right place for this question, your audience is too broad here. Your problem is related to the compilation/configuration options used for gnuplot in the Linux distribution you use, Kubuntu. You should ask this question on a Kubuntu forum or report it as a bug so that the persons responsible for gnuplot on Kubuntu can answer you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I will try later, at this moment I am busy with other things.